# Rails ActionMailer Message Determine Mailer That Created It

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionmailer

Is there a way for a mail message created by ActionMailer via mail() to determine which mailer method created it? Assume that an interceptor wants to determine which mailer and which mailer method it was sent from and to modify something based on this.

Assume this mailer:

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def some_mail
    mail
  end
end
```

And this interceptor:

```
class MailInterceptor
  def self.delivering_email(message)

    # `delivery_handler` exists, and answers question of which Mailer was used
    logger.debug "Mailer:         #{message.delivery_handler}" # "ApplicationMailer"
    # NOTE: `method_name` doesn't exist, it shows the desired functionality
    logger.debug "Message Method: #{message.mailer.method_name}" # "some_mail"

    case message.delivery_handler
    when ApplicationMailer
      message.bcc.append "bccmetoo@test.com" if message.mailer.method_name == "some_mail"
    when OtherMailer
      message.bcc.append "bccthisperson@foo.com"
    end
  end
end
```

Are there such methods, or some way of determining this?

**UPDATE**

Changed the question to reflect how the mailer can be determined by the existing `delivery_handler` method, as answered in the question of which this question was marked a duplicate, but that the exact mailer method used is still unknown.

Comment: This answers the `delivery_handler` part which is awesome. It doesn't solve the need for the specific delivery method used unfortunately.

Comment: Can you correct question in part of 'delivery_handler' to not duplicate with above question?